# Regex and reverse matching group to not matching group

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is there anyway to reverse capturing groups to non-capturing groups and vice versa?

For example we have this one:

```
(a(bc(def)gh)ijk)
```

and we need to do magic for this:

```
(?:a(?:bc(?:def)gh)ijk)
```

of course some magic with finding open/left brackets and replace them with (?: should works, right? no.. consider this one:

`(a(bc(d[(e]f)gh)ijk)`

now we have `[(e]` inside and it means that there can be one char `(` or `e`.

How our replace-algorithm will handle it?

```
(?:a(?:bc(?:d[(?:e]f)gh)ijk)
```

he should not changed `[(e]` to `[(?:e]`

The algorithm I am talking about is another regex:

```
/(\()(?!\?\:)/gi;
```

for finding left brackets that haven't `?:` already.

First you search for these brackets, then you check each of them for prefix `\` because we don't want to change escaped left brackets and finally then you replace them with `(?:`

now.. how to handle these brackets... `[abc(]` ?

Comment: If you wanted to be able to handle all special cases, you'd have to write a parser that understands the regular expression syntax.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to programmatically rewrite a given regex so that it negatively matches any groups it had? How do you want to handle capturing groups? Could you show us some examples of what the resulting regex should look like?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat: Yes. I've already put some examples in my question.

Comment: You've put examples of inputs, but no examples of outputs. And should we handle capturing groups? And what about groups that are already negative matches?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat: all I need is just changing non-capturing to capturing and capturing to non-capturing, my regex is very complex and I need to capture just one group, and I can manipulate/change only this one group or manipulate whole regex string (regex.source).

Comment: Oh. Your post said "matching to non-matching." That's a whole other thing. Either way, it should be possible with some code along with the regex. Expect an answer soon...

Answer (score 1):

The regex I'm using first matches escaped brackets and any char-sets. Then it captures any remaining groups. It excludes negative matches. It also captures if the group is capturing or not, also.

```
var input = /(a(?:bc(d[(e]f)gh)i\(jk[(?!lmnop])/;
var find = /\\\(|\[[^\]]*\]|(\((?!\?!)(?:)?)/g;

input.source.replace(find, function(match, group, capturing) {
  if (group) {
    if (capturing) { return "(?:"; }
    else /* non-capturing */ { return "("; } 
  }
  return match;
});
```